# C++ specific patterns due to language design

Tags: c++, design-patterns, garbage-collection

It took me a long time to realize how important and subtle having variables that:

1) exist on the stack

2) have their destructors called when they fall out of scope

are.

These two things allow things like:

A) RAII

B) refcounted GC

Interesting enough, (1) & (2) are not available in "lower" languages like C/Assembly; nor in "higher" languages like Ruby/Python/Java (since GC prevents predictable destruction of objects).

I'm curious -- what other techniques do you know of that are very C++ specific, due to language design choices.

Thanks!

Edit: If your answer is "this works in C++ & this other langauge", that's okay too. The things I want to learn about are similar to:

By choosing to not have certain features (like GC), we gain other features (like RAII + predicable destructing of objects). In what areas of C++, by choosing to *NOT* have features that other "higher level" langauges have, C++ manages to get patterns that those higher level langauges can't express.

Comment: I don't believe C++ has GC, C# does of course but that is a different beast.

Comment: Yes, resource management via RAII (with or without ref counting) is not really GC, it's much more general.

Comment: Plus it happens at pre-determined times, GC is non-deterministic.

Comment: You can do this in VBScript as well, since GC runs predictably -- you know that the destructor will be run as soon as the object goes out of scope.

Comment: C# has stack allocated objects (both primitives and structs) in its own strange way, nevertheless stack allocated. The language also has `using` declarations and `Disposable` that serve as a first approach into RAII.

Comment: He (or she) means that you can implement your own simple GC in C++ using ref-counting... not that C++ has a GC

Comment: *"C++ manages to get patterns that those higher level langauges can't express"* - It's more like, C++ needs a lot of common practices because it is more dangerous and less expressive than those higher-level languages.

Comment: C++ is less expressive? Thats funny, i love C++ because few languages are that expressive.

Comment: @BlueRaja: Instead of RAII, those languages require the use of a more verbose `using` or `with` pattern. Ironically it seems harder to "leak" a file (leave it open) in C++, than in higher-level languages. The problems with C++ are, that the RAII-idiom doesn't seem to be universally common, and that until C++0x simple and cheap, yet versatile smart pointers like movable `unique_ptr` are not possible. (Smart pointers allow one to avoid `delete`'s in one's code, and I suppose argument forwarding in C++0x makes it technically possible to eliminate `new` as well?)

Comment: @gf: Expressiveness is normally measured in how many statements it takes to do something (a practice started by the excellent *Code Complete*). In that respect, C++ is one of the worst. Here's a copy of the table from *Code Complete* - larger is better: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages#Expressiveness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really love trait classes. Not exactly specific of C++ (other languages as Scala have them), but it allows you to adapt objects, basically to specify a set of operations that a type should support. Imagine that you want a "hasher", in the sense of `tr1::hash`. hash is defined for some types, but not for others. How can you make a class that has a hash defined for all the types that you want? You can declare a class such as:

```
template < typename T>
struct hashing_tratis
{
    typedef std::tr1::hash<T> hashing_type;
};
```

that is, you expect a class that has the correct hasing_type defined to be used. However, hash is not defined, say, for `myType`, so you can write:

```
template <>
struct hashing_traits<myType>
{
    typedef class_that_knows_how_to_hash_myType hashing_type;
};
```

This way, suppose that you need a way to hash any type that you use in your program (including `myType`). You can write an "universal" hasher by creating a hasing trait:

```
template <typename T>
struct something {
    typename hashing_traits<T>::hashing_type hasher;
    .... // here hasher is defined for all your relevant types, and knows how to hash them
```

Comment: Languages that support reflection can do this without the cumbersome traits class. They just ask the class if it supports an interface and calls it. The same is also possible in languages with first order function support.

Comment: jmucchiello: Well, not exactly. What happens, for example, when you ask for a class or interface that this object does not implement? You have to "search" for an adaptator. Type parameterization in C++ allows this trait construction with a homogeneous interface.

Answer (score 7):

[curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

[expression templates](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template)

Probably the whole meta-programming concept as well

Answer (score 2):

Well, this one can be done in the D programming language, as well as the two you mention, but templates powerful enough to essentially function as **compile time duck typing** are pretty useful.  I often feel that a large part of the debate between static and dynamic languages could be resolved by a good enough template system, so that even though types need to be statically resolved at compile time they don't need to be known at development time.  C++ pioneered this idea (at least among mainstream languages).  D takes it several steps further.

With templates and compile-time duck typing you get the best of both worlds:  The flexibility of not having to specify types at development time of a function or class and the safety and performance of knowing them at compile time.

Comment: The question is specifically about C++.

Comment: @Neil:  I'm just pointing out that it's not **completely** specific, though C++ is the most popular language in which this technique is available.

Answer (score 2):

- Always make the caller responsible for memory allocation/deallocation, which means that code that would look like this in Java/C#:

  ```
  MyClass doSomething(MyClass someInstance);
  ```

  looks like this in C/C++:

  ```
  void doSomething(MyClass* someBuffer, MyClass* someInstance);
  ```
- Using destructors to close sockets, file-handles, etc.

Comment: Or `boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> doSomething(const MyClass& someInstance);`

Comment: If you want the FORCE the caller to be responsible for alloc/free you should use references: void doSomething(const myclass& in_param, myclass& out_param); You can't call doSomething with allocating out_param somewhere and passing it in.

Comment: Actually, it's a better practice to take full responsibility for all allocation/dealloc your code should use. You can do this by (1) using smart pointers that will free your allocated resources when no more used and (2) by returning an object by copy and making that copy free it's resources when destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, almost ALL 'design patterns' have a strong tie to C++. You should rather assume they have NOTHING to do with 'proper design' and 'best practices' and EVERYTHING to do with bizarre C++ foibles and carefully consider the real need for any of them instead of mindlessly complicating your code. Especially since many of the design patterns are bandaids to fix problems created by yet other design patterns. This applies ten times more so when using any language than C++, because C++ has a huge number of problems no other language does.

For example, singleton is the most obvious example of this. The real reason for this is the way that C++ has very poorly implemented static initialization. Without this, you actually have to know what you are doing to make initialization work properly, and most people really don't. For most uses the extra overhead of singleton is fine, but it should be kept in mind that it does have overhead, and it has no use in most languages. It also creates extra problems of in every single implementation I have seen.

Same applies to the bridge pattern, I can see using singletons, but there's simply no reason to ever use bridge pattern. It comes down to 'do you know what you are doing?'. If so, you don't need bridge pattern. If not, you should probably learn more before trying to solve the issue prompting you to use bridge pattern. Most importantly, it is not really useful at all in languages besides C++. The point of it is to separate implementation and interface, which in more modern OO languages is done already because they have proper modules of some kind. In C++, it is better to use pure virtual interfaces for cases like this (and don't think this has worse performance, it has much better performance than bridge pattern combined with templates).

But that is the problem with design patterns; it's not a methodology at all, just a bunch of random things. Random things most of the people advocating them don't really understand, most of which properly have no place being called anything with the word design in them. They are not design tools, but specific solutions to various problems. Many of which are avoidable.

Ironically, java API is full of bridges and a wide variety of other design patterns which are totally pointless in Java. Java API is easy to use most of the time, but the overcomplicated heirarchy can be very cumbersome to work with.

Comment: Why should a good templated bridge pattern implementation have worse performance then one based on vtables? Also, bridges are not only a question of modules, hiding complexity with a layer-based approach is its main value regardless of language.

Comment: An additional level of indirection does not affect performance as much as it helps GRASP good habits.
And you are not answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

There's the pImpl idiom. It work similar to the Bridge pattern.

And the [Expression Template](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Expression-template), which delays C++'s expression evaluations.

These two works also explore this question: [More C++ Idioms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms) and [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) (Scott Meyers, 2005)

Answer (score 0):

Few languages support [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) (with [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) being most common) as C++ does, you can do it statically or dynamically.
With it you can let instances interact on each other without yet knowing, or testing for, their concrete type.

Comment: I would say almost ALL languages (except for a few like CLOS that support it natively) support it as C++ does - you have to code it yourself.

Comment: @Hogan: Oh, i have to look that up. Only dynamically though i guess?

Comment: @gf: yeah, see http://blogs.msdn.com/laurionb/archive/2009/08/13/multimethods-in-c-4-0-with-dynamic.aspx